# Searching for specific id's or values with fuse.js

Tags: javascript, json, fuse.js

Im trying to search for specific values in json data. To return 1 specific record I can use the following with the appropriate options to make an exact search etc...

```
fuse.search('197');
```

I am trying to get more than 1 specific record returned and was hoping to do something like...

```
fuse.search('197, 186, 813');
```

Using the demo [here](http://fusejs.io/), if I change the threshhold to 0, how would I search for say John and Steve and only return the 2 records?

Answer (score 3):

Ok looks like I've found my own answer (should have read the docs properly), using the [demo](http://fusejs.io/), tick the **Tokenize** option, in the search field type in john steve Wooster, you will get the 3 specific results you'd expect, sorted.